# How to retrieve annotated instance from Guice's injector?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, configuration, annotations, guice

Let's say I have a module:

```
Module extends AbstractModule
{
  @Override
  protected void configure()
  {
    bind(String.class).
      annotatedWith(Names.named("annotation")).
        toInstance("DELIRIOUS");
  }
}
```

and I want to test the module and check if it injects the right value in a `String` field annotated with `Names.named("annotation")` without having a class and a field but obtaining the value directly from the injector:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
  Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new Module());

  // THIS IS NOT GOING TO WORK!
  String delirious = injector.getInstance(String.class); 

  assertThat(delirious, IsEqual.equalTo("DELIRIOUS");
}
```

Answer (score 236, accepted):

```
injector.getInstance(Key.get(String.class, Names.named("annotation")));
```

Answer (score 16):

I'm using the following method

```
public <T> T getInstance(Class<T> type, Class<? extends Annotation> option) {
    final Key<T> key = Key.get(type, option);
    return injector.getInstance(key);
}
```

for this. In general, you still have the problem of creating the annotation instance, but here `Names.named("annotation")` works.

Comment: I think that it merits mention that the original solution is specifically for the Named specification.  If you have a Annotation (specific Interface @Annotation) that you have created, then you just make the call as the getMethod specific:

injector.getInstance(Key.get(DesiredObject.class, Annotation.class));