# Guice binding two different class to same interface with annotation

Tags: java, guice

I have got a question about binding in Guice.

I have got two classes (MyClass1 and MyClass2) both implement the same interface, say: IMyInteface.

I have got the binding configured as:

bind(IMyInterface.class).annotatedWith(Class1.class).to(MyClass1.class);
bind(IMyInterface.class).annotatedWith(Class2.class).to(MyClass2.class);

The Class1 and Class2 are annotations defined.

Now, if I use this code in the client:

```
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
    IMyInterface c = injector..getInstance(IMyInterface.class);
```

The Guice won't know which implementation I want to have for IMyInterface. Is there anyway I can specify the annotation at this stage to selectively say: I want the implementation of MyClass2?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
injector.getInstance(Key.get(IMyInterface.class, Class2.class));
```

**Edit:**
There appears to be a similar question with a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118082/how-to-retrieve-annotated-instance-from-guices-injector).